# Saving and Loading files from an Android mobile Device using Flash Actionscript 3.0

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, saving-data

Im making a Test Maker App for both Desktop and Android. I was able to save and load in Desktop but failed on Android. I can ONLY save my file, but i cannot load my saved file. The Android device says "No files were found". It doesnt even open a file browser. The type of saving and loading that im doing is the type where the user can actually look for his project and open it. Im currently using FileReference to do this. It works on Desktop but not on Android Mobile.  Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure FileReference works on mobile.   Really you should be using the `FileStream` & `File` classes and saving the `File.applicationStorage` directory.

Comment: Can you show me how? I would appreciate it.

Comment: here is a link for Adobe's docs on reading and writing files with file stream http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc8.html

Comment: can you guys just give me an example? Example on how to save and load an actual file from storage in a android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't use a `FileReference` on mobile (though someone feel free to correct me if wrong).

On mobile, you should use the `File` & `FileStream` classes for loading/saving local files.

Here is an example, of using a compile time constant you could create (to determine if desktop or AIR) and loading appropriately into and out of a textfield called `textfield`:

```
CONFIG::air {
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.txt");

    if(file.exists){
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

        textfield.text = stream.readUTF(); //this may need to changed depending what kind of file data you're reading

        stream.close();
    }else{
        data = "default value"; //file doesn't exist yet
    }
}

CONFIG::desktop {
    //use your file reference code to populate the data variable
}
```

And to save: (assuming you have a textfield whose text you want to save)

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTF(textfield.text);
fileStream.close();
```

There are other save methods besides `writeUTF` (which is for plain text) `writeObject` is good for saving custom object when combined with `flash.net.registerClassAlias`

File classes are in the `flash.filesystem` package

**EDIT**

Here is something you can try for letting the user pick the location on AIR.

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
file.browseForOpen("Open Your File", [new FileFilter("Text Files", "*.txt")]);

function onFileSelected(e:Event):void {
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(e.target as File, FileMode.READ);

    textField.text = stream.readUTF();
}
```

---

```
var saveFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.txt");
saveFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSaveSelect);
saveFile.browseForSave("Save Your File");

function onSaveSelect(e:Event):void {
    var file:File = e.target as File;

    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTF(textField.text);
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Hello LDMS thanks for your reply. Ive tried your code and i have questions regarding your save code.

Why do i reference to the 'file' that i loaded? Sorry if this is a stupid and an amateur question. Im really new to saving/loading. I dont have much knowledge about this. What if i wanted to save a text from a textfield object on stage. ive replaced file with an textfieldObj.text in this code but there was a coercion error so i know its wrong.

Comment: The `File` doesn't have to be the same one you loaded, but most people when they do these things save over the file they loaded.   Not knowing the nature of your load and save operations, I can' really tell you what you should do.    `FileStream` always needs a `File` in order to save/load.  What you can change, is the way you write data into the `FileStream`.    So if it was just plain text from a text field, you would probably want the following:   `fileSream.writeUTF(textfieldObj.text)` - then when you load use `readUTF`

Comment: thanks LDMS. Just a quick question while im trying to figure out this thing.. Does the code that you gave me loads a file browser  that enables the user to look for a file to load on stage? same goes for save? Because thats the type of saving/loading im aiming for. If yes, then wait for my next reply. Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: No, this code doesn't involve user input at all.  From your question, it sounded like you had a good handle on that and needed an example of how load/save on mobile, that is what my code is for.   I'm pretty sure you cant do a `FileReference` so this is likely how you'll need to do it.  Though if you're just talking text, you could use a `SharedObject` instead of saving files.

Comment: The type of Saving/Loading process im aiming for is the same type  of how you save/load in Microsoft Word, Open Office, or even notepad.. When Loading a file, a file browser will appear and allow the user to look for his file to load just like FileReference. FileReference opens a file browser for the user to search his file. But obviously i cant use FileReference because it wont work on Mobile. So what im asking is the same type except it should not be FileReference. Can you help with that? Sorry again

Comment: I'm updating the answer with something else you can try

Comment: Not sure what im doing wrong. When i run i get these errors

>Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.net:FileFilter to an unrelated type Array. 
>Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.filesystem:File.

And it is pointing to these lines

>file.browseForOpen("Open Your File", new FileFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
>stream.open(e.target, FileMode.READ);

Comment: Sorry, the file filter needs to be wrapped in an Array, and we need to cast e.target as a File, I'll update the code in the answer

Comment: The save function saves the file as File, while the load function looks for a text file. So i cannot open my saved file.

Comment: It worked!! thanks man. I have another question but i think ill ask other people here. Thanks for your help and your patience.

Comment: It worked!! But when i tried it on mobile, again it said "No files were found". The mobile didnt open a file browser. Thanks for all your help man.Thank you for being patient with me.. I'll ask other people here for help too.

Comment: Again, you may need to write your own save as dialog,  you can scan the directory with `FileInstance.getDirectoryListing()` - which will return an array of all the `File`s in that directory.   Maybe if I have time later I'll make an example.

Comment: I just read about getDirectoryListing just a few minutes ago.. I think i will try that because probably thats my only option. I will create my own fileBrowser for both save/load process. This way i can limit the user's actions like saving in different directories.

Comment: Hi again LDMS. I was able to create my own file browser and ive tried it on mobile. It was a success thanks to you. I just have one problem. How can i name my own File? i mean why do we need to set the name of the File in the code? I was so sure that i was going to solve this problem, but theres always an I/O error. Can you take a look at my code?

Comment: Hey LDMS, thanks again for all your help. Without you i wouldnt be able to do this. I was able to create my own File Browser and it worked in my Android Mobile. I just have one problem. How can i name my own File to save? I was so sure that i was going to solve this problem but somehow it always return an I/O error.

Comment: Here is my code
//This is where i set the name of the File to be saved by entering the  name that i want in the textfield on stage. 
var tempName:String = txtName.text + ".txt"

  //inside the resolvePath, ive entered tempName
 var savefile:File = folder.resolvePath(tempName);
  var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
  fileStream.open(savefile, FileMode.WRITE);
  fileStream.writeUTFBytes(saveTxt.text);
  fileStream.close();

Comment: I can save and load using filestream.. My new question is how do i delete a file using filestream? Lets say i have my file saved in this location, so how do i delete it.

    var folder:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("MyApp/images/image001.jpg")

Comment: you use the `deleteFile()` method of a File object.